# Fast file handling in multithreading mode

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I am developing a web application in java. It has a file that is read on every page request, but I have to think about changing it (which is rare). You need to come up with something to make everything work as quickly as possible. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sort of copy_on_change.
If your file is /path/myFile_v1.txt
Write a code similar to

```
private AtomicInteger version=1;

public String getFilePath() {
    return "/path/myFile_v"+version.get()+".txt"
}

public void synchronized makeAChange() {
     // create a new copy of the file with some changes
     version.incrementAndGet();
}
```

you can remove old copies after some time or remove version-2 each time.
Reading threads are not blocked while you make changes.

Comment: Thank you. But I wanted a slightly different process.
There is a thought, but I don't really like it. I can create a resource with a file cache. When accessing a resource, it checks the file modification flag, and if the flag is true, it updates the cache. If false then transfer the cache.